Error: processing response error
Solidity
const ethers=require("ethers");
const fs=require("fs-extra");

async function main(){
  //http://127.0.0.1:7545
  const provider=new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("RPC_SERVER");
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet("PRIVATE_KEY",provider);

  const abi=fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi","utf8");
  const binary=fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin","utf8")

  const contractFactory=new ethers.ContractFactory(abi,binary,wallet);
  console.log("Deploying wait...")
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({ gasLimit: 6721975,gasPrice:20000000000 });
  const transactionReceipt=await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
  console.log("this is transaction receipt:");
  console.log(transactionReceipt)
  console.log("this is contract.deployTransaction:")
  console.log(contract.deployTransaction)
}

main()
.then(()=>{
  process.exit(0);
})
.catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error);
  process.exit(1);
})

Error: processing response error



 reason: 'processing response error',
  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',



error: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
      at getResult (/home/kakarot/folder1/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:191:21)
      at processJsonFunc (/home/kakarot/folder1/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:356:22)
      at /home/kakarot/folder1/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:288:46
      at step (/home/kakarot/folder1/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (/home/kakarot/folder1/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (/home/kakarot/folder1/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: -32000,
    data: {
      hash: '0x391ddb12f099addac55c026160a6be0feca1dad24b3aedb51b47c1390f2635fa',
      programCounter: 23,
      result: '0x391ddb12f099addac55c026160a6be0feca1dad24b3aedb51b47c1390f2635fa',
      reason: null,
      message: 'invalid opcode'
    }
  },


Post your solidity code

Post your ethers library verison
